# where can I find grpc library for c++ windows and Linux both

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to setup grpc server for a embedded device which runs the C++ environment. I have followed the link at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/INSTALL.md, but I am unable to understand what needs to be done there in a order for grpc library to be available or installed in C++ libs.

Setting up grpc for C++, I assume to be having a generic approach for windows/Linux environment apart from the specifics of C++ run time location

The approach at above location says to build, but its failing for me at step,

[image]

With error as below,

[image]

Anyone if having more detailed link/reference to step by step process would be really helpful

Comment: So are you trying to build for Windows or for Linux? Your question is unclear on this

Comment: My target environment is linux device, but for development purposes I am doing it on windows 7

Comment: So which of the two builds is failing? The Windows one? How are you building (which compiler, have you installed all the prerequisites, etc.)?

Comment: Yes Windows one. I did all the steps above. I am using Cygwin GCC compiler. I have installed all the items given, at    ----------                                       Building using CMake (with BoringSSL)

Install CMake.
Install Active State Perl (choco install activeperl)
Install Ninja (choco install ninja)
Install Go (choco install golang)
Install yasm and add it to PATH (choco install yasm)

Comment: If you are setting up to use the CMake build path, then you should also use the commands they describe there, not use `make` instead (which requires a different setup as described in the section right below it)

Comment: Even with CMake the last line says to run some commands in repo root, --> Run these commands in the repo root directory. Which is folder where I have cloned --> git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc. Please correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: And right below that is a list of commands you are supposed to run, which are not the commands you have shown in your screenshots

Comment: Yes but in which location or folder should I be running those commands? I thought its repo root which is /grpc itself cloned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building gRPC under Windows nowadays, I would highly encourage people to use the provided CMakefile.

We haven't done any work towards supporting cygwin however, and we don't have any plans in supporting it at the moment. Most of the Windows-specific codebase would expect msys/mingw or VC, and I wouldn't be surprised if it would fail at runtime with cygwin even if you manage to compile, as our usage of the Linux API is probably too advanced for cygwin's emulation layer.

The Makefile should potentially behave properly under msys, if you insist on using it.

Comment: Well, I got it working at some point and sent a PR for it (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/9715#issuecomment-279920911), but it never got enough attention to be merged and recently there were some breaking changes (mostly due to inclusion of cares) that require some more love